# UpdateSourceTrigger not being applied to Styled Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, .net-4.0

I recently solved a styling question with some help here at stack overflow... (you can see the question/ answer in my history)

As a result of that, I came up with the following style to apply to specific text boxes.

```
<!--Expanding text box with the max width in the tag property-->
<!---->
<!--Will not work with password box!!-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
       x:Key="ExpandingTextBoxMaxWidthInTag">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*">
                            <ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth>
                                <Binding Path="Tag"
                                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                </Binding>
                            </ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth>
                        </ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox>
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Text"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                        </TextBox.Text>
                        <TextBox.MaxWidth>
                            <Binding Path="Tag"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                        </TextBox.MaxWidth>
                    </TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**(Code Listing 1)**

Which I then apply to text boxes in my code like so...

```
<TextBox Tag="150"
         Text="{Binding Path=Username}"
         Style="{StaticResource ExpandingTextBoxMaxWidthInTag}" />
```

**(Code Listing 2)**

I must stress, that as written, this code works as desired. The problem arises when, I add ***UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged*** to the binding on the ***Text*** property...

```
<TextBox Tag="150"
         Text="{Binding Path=Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Style="{StaticResource ExpandingTextBoxMaxWidthInTag}" />
```

**(Code Listing 3)**

The code in listing 3 works with one exception: the update source trigger does not fire appropriately. Instead of firing on every keystroke (like it would without the style applied), it only fires on the lost focus event (the default).

I cannot simply apply the "PropertyChanged" explicitly in the style because I need to apply the style to a bunch of TextBoxes with varying needs regarding the update source trigger.

How can I get the specified update source trigger in my xaml to filter down to my style?

Comment: Could you use a control template instead? Make a new control with a content control and use TemplateBinding. TemplateBinding does pass through the rest of the binding properties.

Answer (score 0):

You override the "Text" Property with your style and therefor also the "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" part, don´t you? Just remove the "Text" Property binding in your Style and this should work fine imo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at? Yes, I override the text property with my style, but I override it with what I set in XAML, and the XAML contains the correct UpdateSourceTrigger

Comment: I overlooked your <Binding> Tag in the Style...i´m used so to {} markup :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for answering so late. As I've also faced this issue I find it necessary to post here anyway.

##### Problem

As I understand, your styled textbox fails to trigger the UpdateSource event on every keystroke because the textbox in the Control Template has UpdateSourceTrigger set to a default value in a Text property.

##### Solution

Just need to set UpdateSourceTrigger inside your Control Template

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
               x:Key="ExpandingTextBoxMaxWidthInTag">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                    Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*">
                                    <ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth>
                                        <Binding Path="Tag"
                                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                        </Binding>
                                    </ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth>
                                </ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!-- Code with changes -->
                            
                            <TextBox>
                                <TextBox.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                </TextBox.Text>

                                <TextBox.MaxWidth>
                                    <Binding Path="Tag"
                                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                </TextBox.MaxWidth>
                            </TextBox>
                            
                            <!-- /Code with changes -->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```